# Custom UINavigationBar within container view controller sub views

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to recreate the look of Snapchat signup/login screen where the background is the live camera feed but blurred slightly. My initial thought was to use Brad Larson's [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). After running some tests however, the results weren't great - no where near as smooth as Snapchat's implementation.

I noticed that the standard iOS 7+ `UINavigationBar` creates this blurred effect perfectly and with no lag. Creating a custom subclass of `UINavigationBar` to extend it's height works very well and has the desired effect.

A couple of questions:

1. I've been told that it isn't a good idea to subclass `UINavigationBar` as subsequent updates can break the app. Can anyone think of a better way to achieve this effect?
2. How do I get the `UINavigationBar` to sit as a background layer/view so my content simply sits on top?
3. I have a `UIScrollView` setup similar to Snapchat - swipe left/right to show different views. Whilst I want this `UINavigationBar` background for most of my views, I don't want it on some views. How can I go about removing the background for these views? I have tried popping `self.navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)` in `viewDidAppear` but it's removing the navigation bar for all views.

**EDIT BELOW**

I have worked out how to do question 3. Instead of modifying the navigation controller's navigation bar, I have added a separate `UINavigationBar` for the views and made it full screen by setting the frame from within `layoutSubviews`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen Apple's example app [GLCameraRipple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html)? It's a little old so probably doesn't use the latest GLKit stuff, but it essentially shows you how to process the camera output using your own shaders.

Comment: Haven't seen it before, just had a quick look. Appears to be performing similar function to Larson's GPUImage framework. The UINavBar performs great, no idea why they don't allow us to use that background style for `UIViews` and the like